# Tensorflow federated-learning giving error in colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to run the [Tensorflow federated tutorial on colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.5.0/docs/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=coAumH42q9nz).

However, so far, the `from tensorflow_federated import python as tff` code is giving the following error:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-af7e4c5121d6> in <module>()
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 from tensorflow_federated import python as tff

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/common_libs/structure.py in <module>()
    263 
    264 def to_odict(struct: Struct,
--> 265              recursive: bool = False) -> collections.OrderedDict[str, Any]:
    266   """Returns `struct` as an `OrderedDict`, if possible.
    267 

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

TFF's recent releases have been compatible only with Python 3.9 and later; Google Colab's hosted runtimes are still on Python 3.7.

Likely the quickest way to run these notebooks is to run your own local runtime using Python 3.9, and connect the notebooks there; instructions on doing this from Colab can be found [here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html).

Answer (score 0):

While installing tensorflow_federated on colab (`!pip install -q --upgrade tensorflow_federated`)

I got the following error:

> pymc 5.1.2 requires cachetools>=4.2.1, but you have cachetools 3.1.1 which is incompatible.
>
> orbax 0.1.7 requires jax>=0.4.6, but you have jax 0.3.15 which is incompatible.
>
> google-colab 1.0.0 requires portpicker~=1.3.1, but you have portpicker 1.5.2 which is incompatible.
>
> flax 0.6.8 requires jax>=0.4.2, but you have jax 0.3.15 which is incompatible.
>
> chex 0.1.7 requires jax>=0.4.6, but you have jax 0.3.15 which is  incompatible.
>
> arviz 0.15.1 requires scipy>=1.8.0, but you have scipy 1.7.3 which is incompatible.

So I installed the following packages:

`!pip install -q --upgrade tensorflow`

`!pip install -q cachetools>=4.2.1`

`!pip install -q jax>=0.4.6`

`!pip install -q portpicker~=1.5`

`!pip install -q scipy>=1.8.0`

`!pip install -q --upgrade tensorflow_federated`

`!pip install -q --upgrade nest_asyncio`

Installing `portpicker~=1.3.1` was giving error so I went for `portpicker~=1.5`.

This will install the latest version of `tensorflow-federated` (0.54.0).

Answer (score 0):

The code you have used to import tensorflow_federated (`from tensorflow_federated import python as tff`) is not correct.

Please import tensorflow_federated using  - `import tensorflow_federated as tff`

Despite showing some pip dependency error, I am able to successfully install the TF Federated in Google Colab. Please check the below screenshot:

[image]